# Why ist Jenkins job-dsl plugin failing with ERROR: java.io.IOException: Failed to persist config.xml

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a Jenkins Job DSL job that worked well until about january (it is not used that often). Last week, the job failed with the error message `ERROR: java.io.IOException: Failed to persist config.xml` (no Stack trace, just that message). There were no changes to the job since the last successful execution in january.

```
[...]
13:06:22 Processing provided DSL script
13:06:22 New run name is '#15 (Branch_B20_2_x)'
13:06:22 ERROR: java.io.IOException: Failed to persist config.xml
13:06:22 [WS-CLEANUP] Deleting project workspace...
13:06:22 [WS-CLEANUP] Deferred wipeout is used...
13:06:22 [WS-CLEANUP] done
13:06:22 Finished: FAILURE
```

I thougt that between january and noew, maybe some plugin was updated and the DSL script is now wrong, so I changed my DSL script to the most easy one I could imagine (example from job-dsl plugin page):

```
job('example') {
  steps {
    shell('echo Hello World!')
  }
}
```

But the job still fails with the exact same error.
I checked the jenkins logs but nothing to see.
I am running jenkins in a docker swarm container and each job is executed in an own build agent conatiner using docker-swarm-plugin (no changes to that either, worked in january).
The docker deamon logs also show no errors.

The filesystem for the workspace of jenkins also is not full and the user in the build agent container has write access to taht file system.
It even does not work, when I mount an empty tmpfs to the workspace.

Does anyone have an idea what goes wrong or at least a hint where to continue searching for that error?

- Jenkins version: 2.281
- job-dsl plugin version: 1.77
- Docker version: 20.10.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved by updating jenkins to 2.289

Seems like there war some problem with the combination of the versions before. I will keep you updated if some of the next updates chnages anything.